# How to click the same button on Tkinter python once the process completed with threading

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have simple program with only one function which process files and then converts to pdf on a press of button. initially `GUI` window freezes while the function was running, after this I introduced threading into the program and now `GUI` freezing issue was resolved, but now when press the button again it shows below error

[image]

if anyone can help me on how to fix this and also explain how it works, that will be really helpful, as I am new to python and just started using `Tkinter`.

sample code would be even more helpful.

Comment: It is better to provide a [mre].

Comment: Please post Traceback error as text not an image. Too lazy to zoom-in.

Comment: Please find the error below

Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python39_64\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python39_64\lib\threading.py", line 887, in start
    raise RuntimeError("threads can only be started once")
RuntimeError: threads can only be started once

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use the old thread object you used on the first button click. Instantiate a new one instead.

This is because, you can't start the same thread twice.

So maybe keep a list of threads and add a new one with each button click.

Comment: thank you so much for you answer, please give a small example code, that will be really helpful